# Spacing inline-block elements (with variable widths) on multiple rows within a fixed width padded container

Tags: css, spacing

I have some `<input type="radio"/ >` radio buttons that are used as toggle buttons according to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidelrizzo/DYJkG/

The buttons themselves have variable widths and are grouped inside a `<div class="toggle-btn-grp">`.

The buttons-group is itself is located in a parent `<div>` with fixed width (blue lines in the picture) and padding (pink lines).

[image: multiple inline-block elements with variable widths in a fixed-width container]

Currently, the buttons are spaced with `margin-right:1em`.
The rightmost element on each row should however not have any right-margin (or this one should overflow the padding of the grand-parent container).

As we see, there is enough space for button #6 to stay on the same row as button #5, if it did not have a margin on its right.

**How can I achieve this?**

Here's the XHTML:

```
<div class="toggle-btn-grp" style="padding-top:0.3em;padding-bottom:0.3em;word-spacing:-.3em;" >
    <label onclick="" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="1" />1</label>
    <label onclick="" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="2 "/>2</label>
    <label onclick="" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="3" />3</label>
(...)
</div>
```

and the CSS of the toggle buttons:

```
/* Toggle buttons */

label { 
    padding:0.3em 1em 0.3em 0; 
}
.toggle-btn-grp { 
}


.toggle-btn { 
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center; 
    min-width:3em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    margin-right:1em;
    padding:0.2em 1em; 
    /*background-color:#f8f8f8;*/
    border-radius:0.2em; 
    border:solid 2px #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn { 
    margin:5px 0; 
    padding:0.2em 0.1em; 
    border-radius:0px;
    border-right-color:#fff;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle {
  display:inline-block;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn:first-child { 
    margin-left:2px; 
    border-radius: 0.2em 0px 0px 0.1em; 
}
.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn:last-child { 
    margin-right:2px;  
    border-radius: 0px 0.2em 0.1em 0px;
    border-right:solid 1px #ccc;
}


.toggle-btn:hover { 
    border:solid 2px #888 !important;
    color:#000;
    background:#def;
}

.toggle-btn.active {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight:bold; 
    background:#a2dafe;
    border:solid 1px #888 !important; 
}


.visuallyhidden { 
    border: 0; 
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    height: 1px; 
    margin: -1px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 1px; 
}
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, .visuallyhidden.focusable:focus { 
    clip: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: visible; 
    position: static; 
    width: auto; 
}
```

**Note 1**. So far, the best solution I found is adding the right margin only to odd elements.
This works for me only because there is place to display two buttons per row, but would not work if the buttons had more variations in their width:

```
.toggle-btn:nth-child(odd) {
 margin-right:1em;
}
```

**Note 2**. I tried using a flex layout, but it didn't work for me:

```
.toggle-btn-grp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.toggle-btn {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the `gap` property on CSS grid. 
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

The gap is only applied between items. Something like this could get it started.

```
.toggle-btn-grp {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    column-gap: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margins, make use of the white space you already have in your matkup between the labels and stretch it using letter-spacing or word-spacing to get whatever gap you want. Because space characters are automatically dropped at the ends of line boxes, the labels will fit nicely.

```css
/* Toggle buttons */

.toggle-btn-grp { 
  padding-top:0.3em;
  padding-bottom:0.3em;
  letter-spacing:0.65em; /* this controls the gap between the labels */
}

.toggle-btn { 
  font-size:1rem;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center; 
  margin-bottom:1em;
  padding:0.2em 1em; 
  border-radius:0.2em; 
  border:solid 2px #ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
  letter-spacing:0em; /* resets the spacing inside the labels */
}

/* Just for demo purposes */

body {
  width:155px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}
body::before, body::after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-right:1px solid pink;
}

body::before {
  left:10px;
}
body::after {
  right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-btn-grp">
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="1" />1</label>
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="2 "/>2</label>
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="3" />3</label>
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="10" />10</label>
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="20 "/>20</label>
    <label class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="brand" value="100" />100</label>
</div>
```